# Check for new post on forum every hour Swift

Tags: swift, background-fetch

I am making a app that is checking if there is new posts and threads on a forum page like reddit. The app is notifying the user when there is a new post, with background fetch, but if the user closes the app, the background fetch doesn't work. Also, the app isn't updating exactly every hour, but maybe just every 5-10 hour. Is there another way of updating in the background, like sending remote notification, and if, how?

Comment: If this app works, it's a nightmare for forum providers.

Answer (score 0):

The only sensible way would to leverage silent push notifications.

Silent notifications do not show up for the users, but they do wake up the app.

It's very easy to send a silent push. [More here...](http://hayageek.com/ios-silent-push-notifications/)

Comment: As I understand silent push notifications, you have to send the notification from the web-page, but I don't have access to the page.